# How do we make a choice whether to create new webparts as projects in solution or new items in project?

Tags: visual-studio

In VS we create a solution.

Then, we can create multiple projects under this. Also, we can add multiple new items under each project.

Suppose requirement is to create a webpart, then how is decision made whether to go for new project in solution. OR new item in an existing project?

Answer (score 1):

You should watch out, that solutions don't get messy or too big. Don't put too many projects inside a solution, it will be impossible to find a webpart then if you have many of them with many projects inside. I always make one solution for like one page, with all the webparts in it inside one project and every "item" of them is in a separate feature. Because if needed, you are able to deactivate not needed ones - one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can find similar questions [Organizing WebParts in Visual Studio - Best Practices](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/organizing-webparts-in-visual-studio-best-practices) and [Structure of SharePoint Solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3084/structure-of-sharepoint-solution).

> When working with SharePoint 2010 and the Visual Studio Tools for
>   SharePoint, you can effectively structure your project how you like -
>   this is because you can use folders to structure things logically

I agree with Chris O'Brien. For example, you have a web part which performs actions on a list, in this case I prefer to include web part to the project with this list.